# maven project can't load Log4j.properties file in cmd run?

Tags: maven, logging

Code:

```
public class TestLog{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestLog.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("test log");
    }
}
```

Console output:

> G:\work\Workspaces\eclipse20151214\Pack\target>java -cp Pack-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   com.zzy.pack.TestLog
>
> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.zzy.pack.TestLog).
>
> log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>
> log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: Just make it available to classpath, is the properties packed in .jar file ?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Maven. Maven is mainly is a build tool. So, Maven has built a jar for you (I assume you've run something like `mvn install` beforehand and got Pack-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar).

Now the running itself is from command line and this means that you will construct the classpath by yourself. In this case just ensure that `log4j.jar` is in the classpath and add it to the Java process script.